# Summing a list of list returning a single value

Tags: python, list

I'm having difficulty with a class assignment summing a list of list to return a single value. The code being asked is:

Implement the function called sum_2D_list, which takes in a Python list of lists and returns a single sum of all the elements in the list of lists. The return value should be a single number.

```
list_of_lists = [[1,4,54], [23,25], [64,11,23], [53,2,6,45]]
print(list_of_lists)


def sum_2D_list(twoD_list):
    """
    A function that takes in a 2-dimensional list (i.e., a list of lists) and returns the total sum of all the numerical elements as a single number.

    Parameters
    ----------
    twoD_list: A list of list (i.e., a 2-dimensional list)
    
    Returns
    -------
    total: the sum of all the numerical elements in all the sublists
    """
```

Now I've tried:

```
twoD_list = sum(sum(list_of_lists,[]))

sum_2D_list(twoD_list)
```

But I get an NameError: name 'twoD_list' is not defined

I am obviously thinking this is going to be way easier than what it is...

Comment: IMO the class should have taught how function definitions work with a really simple example (like “define a function that adds 1 to its input”) before having you define a function that does nested iteration.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is fill in the `sum_2D_list` function (within which `twoD_list` takes the value of whatever the function is called with as an argument), and then call it with `list_of_lists` as an argument:

```
list_of_lists = [[1,4,54], [23,25], [64,11,23], [53,2,6,45]]
print(list_of_lists)

def sum_2D_list(twoD_list):
    return sum(sum(i) for i in twoD_list)

print(sum_2D_list(list_of_lists))
```

The first `print` call prints the list of lists, the second `print` call prints the result of summing all of the elements:

```
[[1, 4, 54], [23, 25], [64, 11, 23], [53, 2, 6, 45]]
311
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way of doing it would be summing all the small lists and then summing the big list thus created.

````
sum_list = sum([sum(small_list) for small_list in list_of_lists])
print(sum_list)```
````